# How to convert an array into comma separated strings in smarty template?

Tags: php, arrays, smarty, implode

I've an array titled `$preview_data` assigned to smarty template as follows:

```
Array
(
  [applicable_states] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 10
            [4] => 11
        )

)
```

Now I want to show the above array elements as comma separated values in a div element of a smarty template. In short it should behave like **implode()** in php. Can someone please help me in achieving this in smarty template? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is that what you are looking for http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=53566

Comment: Did you try `{', '|implode:$array['applicable_states']}`?

Comment: @AmalMurali:It's working perfect for me after doing some modification. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try this:

```
{', '|implode:$preview_data.applicable_states}
```

It will give you what you are expecting. Cheers!!!

Comment: You saved my day but aren't here anymore to get my gratitude :(