# How to use join() function in a Smarty template?

Tags: php, smarty

I am trying these variations but none are working:

```
{$css_scope|join:$css_scope:" "}
{$css_scope|join(' ')}
{$css_scope|join:" "}

etc...
```

basically want to do the equivilent of

```
$css_scope = array('a', 'b', 'c');
join($css_scope, " ");
a b c // output should be this
```

Comment: By the example here (`implode()` and `join()` are the same), you should be able to `{' '|join:$css_scope}` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306281/how-to-convert-an-array-into-comma-separated-strings-in-smarty-template

Comment: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifiers.tpl and if security is enabled, you need to permit `join()` as  a modifier...